# Out of sync when I render whole the frames but it's OK when I render sub of it

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, audio

I have two video in blender with 30 frame/second for both of them. When I play the video in blender, everything is fine. When I use animation button for whole the frames, in the middle of video, audio and video are not sync, but when I do the same thing for just sub-frames (for example 200 frames), the output is Ok. I am totally confused and don't know what's the problem.

Comment: where is the audio coming from? Is this something in the VSE, or a 3D scene being rendered?

Comment: @David, thanks for your reply, I have two videos (both 30 fps), I want to merge them (one is small besides the other one), the audio is a strip of one of videos. I should mention that in some points, I change two videos sizes with gamma cross.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender has an integrated feature for this very problem. Under your timeline, you have a sync too. If you set this to 'Frame Dropping', it will skip some frames during playback if your fps rate is too slow. This way it keeps the video in sync with real time.
[image]

Comment: Oh, Thank you! I searched a lot and set it to Av-Sync to avoid this syncing problem. I tried to set fps rate to 30, why is this happening? why too slow?

Comment: In blender, if you set your framerate after you have made your animation, your animation is going to slow down or speed up with the same factor as how you changed your framerate. Also, in the top left of the viewport, you can see if your framerate is at 30 fps. If not, your pc probably can't handle the playback. It's due to hardware quality.

Comment: Sorry, if it is about hardware, why the output of sub frames is OK?

Comment: If you render your frames in video format, they don't have to be calculating your scene while playing back. It's become video.